# Compare a regex match from two separate files and replace with values from one of them

Tags: python, regex, sed

I'm not really sure how is the best way to do this... I was thinking I might need to do it in python?

- `filea.html` contains `data-tx-text="9817db21ccc2d9acc021c4536690b90a_se"`
- `fileb.html` contains `data-tx-text="0850235fcb0e503150c224dad3156312_se"`

There are the exact same occurrences of `data-tx-text` values from `filea.html` to `fileb.html` (171).

I want to be able to use a regex pattern or a simple Python program to

1. Find `data-tx-text="(.*?)"` in `filea.html`
2. Find `data-tx-text="(.*?)"` in `fileb.html`
3. Replace the value from `filea.html` with the value found in `fileb.html`
4. Move to the next occurrence.
5. Continue until the end of the file, or until all values in `filea.html` match those in `fileb.html`

I have the basics. For instance, I know the regex pattern that I need, and I am guessing I need to loop this in Python or something similar?

Maybe I can do it with sed, but I'm not that good with that, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is Perl an acceptable language?

Comment: If filea.html only have a single value for every occurrence of the data-tx-text attribute, and fileb.html does too, it's a good job for sed, e.g. `sed 's/9817db21ccc2d9acc021c4536690b90a_se/0850235fcb0e503150c224dad3156312_se/g' filea.html`. If not, does each file have the same number of data-tx-text attributes, and is the order of them in the document tree significant?

Comment: If perl is the only way to do it , sure. Not really familiar with perl however

Comment: @flesk - each file has the exact same number of attributes, it would just need to go through them 1 by 1 and replace as found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I have solved it using python, its a bit manual in that i have to change the names of filea and fileb each time, but it works

I think i can improve the regex with escapes?

```
import re
import sys

with open('filea.html') as originalFile:
    originalFileContents = originalFile.read()

pattern = re.compile(r'[0-9a-f]{32}_se')
originalMatches = pattern.findall(originalFileContents)

counter = 0

def replaceId(match):
    global counter
    value = match.group()
    newValue = originalMatches[counter]
    print counter, '=> replacing', value, 'with', newValue
    counter = counter + 1
    return newValue

with open('fileb.html') as targetFile:
    targetFileContents = targetFile.read()

changedTargetFileContents = pattern.sub(replaceId, targetFileContents)
print changedTargetFileContents

new_file = open("Output.html", "w")
new_file.write(changedTargetFileContents)
new_file.close()
```

Available on Github: https://github.com/timm088/rehjex-py

Comment: Doesn't Python support curly bracket quantifiers in regular expressions? E.g. `.{32}` instead of `................................`.

Comment: Improved the regex using r'[0-9a-f]{32}_se'

Answer (score 0):

- open filea find stringa
- open fileb find stringb
- replace stringa with stringb
- replace stringb with stringa
- Write files back

In code as below

```
import re
pattern = 'data-tx-text="(.*?)"'
With open('filea.html', 'r') as f: 
    filea = f.read()
With open('fileb.html', 'r') as f: 
    fileb = f.read()
stringa= re.match(pattern, filea).group()
stringb= re.match(pattern, fileb).group()
filea = filea.replace(stringa, stringb)
fileb = fileb.replace(stringb, stringa)
with open('filea.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(filea)
with open('filea.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fileb)
```

Comment: Would this keep looping through each occurrence (there is 171 matches in each filea and fileb)

Comment: the replace would replace all occurrences.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: I just used the regex you used, i didnt check if it worked on your testcase. you might need to update that to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In `awk`, you could use something like this:

```
NR == FNR {
    match($0, /data-tx-text="[^"]+"/);
    if (RSTART > 0) {
        data[++a] = substr($0, RSTART + 14, RLENGTH - 15);
    }
    next;
}

/data-tx-text/ {
    sub(/data-tx-text="[^"]+"/, "data-tx-text=\"" data[++b] "\"");
    print;
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with awk, how would i run this from the command line, create a shell script?

Comment: Something like 'awk -f program filea.html fileb.html' ?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/(.*)(data-tx-text="[^"]+")(.*)/,a) {
    if (NR==FNR) {
        fileb[++bcnt] = a[2]
    }
    else {
        $0 = a[1] fileb[++acnt] a[3]
    }
}
NR>FNR

$ awk -f tst.awk fileb filea
data-tx-text="0850235fcb0e503150c224dad3156312_se"
```

with other awks you'd use 3 calls to substr() after the match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/data-tx-text="[^"]+"/) {
    if (NR==FNR) {
        fileb[++bcnt] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    }
    else {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) fileb[++acnt] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
NR>FNR

$ awk -f tst.awk fileb filea
data-tx-text="0850235fcb0e503150c224dad3156312_se"
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it only outputs to the shell, how do I make it write to each file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `to each file` - you only have 2 input files and 1 output stream. Add `> filec` on the end of the script execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

replacements, replaced_html = [], ''

with open('fileb.html') as fileb:
    # Extract replacements
    soup = bs(fileb, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.get('data-tx-text'))
    replacements = [tag.get('data-tx-text') for tag in tags]

with open('filea.html') as filea:
    # Replace values
    soup = bs(filea, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.get('data-tx-text'))
    for tag in tags:
        tag['data-tx-text'] = replacements.pop(0)
    replaced_html = str(soup)

with open('filea.html', 'w') as new_filea:
    # Update file
    new_filea.write(replaced_html)
```